# PowerShell Delete folders older than X days readed from a txt file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

how can I check if paths passed from a txt file are older than X days?
then, if yes I want to remove them.

It's not my business to check data-modified of files in the folders. I want to check only the data-created of the folder.

I'm newbie of Powershell so, at the moment, I know to work only on files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll find this by searching SO and google. Being a "newbie" doesn't mean that you can't give it a try yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare the `CreationTime` property of the object to the date of X days ago:

```
$x = 42
$f = Get-Item C:\Temp\foo.txt

if ($f.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$x)) { $f.Delete }
```